# Removing last string from being printed in Java

Tags: java

I made a program that stores user inputted strings to a queue and then prints out the whole thing, but I am having some issues with blocking the string ''end'' from being printed out when printing the string queue.

```
public class Test {

    protected static String testinfo;
    Test() {
        testinfo= "blank";
    }

    public static void setTest(String newInfo){
        testInfo = newInfo;
    }

    public static String getTest(){
        return testInfo;
    }

    private static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Queue<String> queue = new LinkedList<String>();
        String newInfo;

        System.out.println("Inset information for the test or quit by typing end ");

        while (true) {
            System.out.println("Insert information: ");
            newInfo = input.nextLine();

            Test.setTest(newInfo);

            queue.offer(Test.getTest());

            if (newInfo.equals("end")){
                break;
            }
        }

        while(queue.peek() !=null) {
            String x = queue.poll();
            if(x.contains("end")) {
                queue.remove("end");
            }
            System.out.println(x + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you adding it to the queue at all?

Comment: You remove it from the q, but always print it out. Put the `println` in an `else`.

Comment: while(!(queue.peek.equals(("end")))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In while loop, you have already offered the user entered String - `end` to the queue, before you check for break condition. As a matter of fact, the String - `end` is enqueued.

Re-arranging the statements in while loop should solve the issue you are facing

```
    while (true) {
        System.out.println("Insert information: ");
        newInfo = input.nextLine();
        if (newInfo.equals("end")){
            break;
        }
        Test.setTest(newInfo);
        queue.offer(Test.getTest());
    }
```

**Note:** I din't refactor other parts of your code.